# python wget.download() stopped working

Tags: python, python-2.7, wget

I used the following code to download a .msi file before and it worked.
(I am not using the actual URL just one for demo purpose)

downloaded_file = wget.download("https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/python-2.7.14.amd64.msi")

But now suddenly I am getting this error. Note: recently my pc got infected by virus. Can that be any reason?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/rough.py", line 3, in <module>
    downloaded_file = wget.download("https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/python-2.7.14.amd64.msi")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1263, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 363, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:661)
```

As suggested I used the requests module but nothing seems to happen.

```
import requests

req = requests.get("https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/python-2.7.14.amd64.msi" , stream = True)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT: As per the solution given by kabanus I executed theses lines on cmd

[image]
still no wget.download() gives the same error.

Comment: It would help to know the actual url. Maybe something changed on the server.

Comment: What version of python 2.7 are you using? Earlier point releases of 2.7 have some issues with some SSL/TLS versions. It's possible the remote server has been upgraded to only use newer cipher suites and your version of python can't understand the newer version.

Comment: Also what version of the wget package are you using?

Comment: you mave have better luck with the `requests` module

Comment: I forgot to ask - if you paste the url in the browser - does it work (download automatically)?

Comment: Actual url is "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/python-2.7.14.amd64.msi". As you can see it is of the python installer itself. Thus in order to keep confusion away I din't give the actual url. And yes pasting it actually works. @kabanus

Comment: @TomDalton I am using python 2.7.14

Comment: I'd agree with @Jean-FrançoisFabre that you're likely better off using requests. After your `response = request.get(....)` you need to do something with `response.content` which will be the actual (streamed) file content.

Comment: @TomDalton Can you please give me the exact code to Download this msi file using requests

Comment: I have just installed python and python-wget on a clean Windows 10 ubuntu subsystem and it downloaded your file perfectly. Do you have `openssl`,`libssl`, and `python-openssl` packages? Also, could a proxy changed on your side?

Comment: Yes a proxy changed on my side. First I did it on my home wifi now I am trying to use it on my university wifi. What should I then? @kabanus

Comment: I think you should consult a technical admin in your school, I'm suspecting not only the proxy, but missing packages and SSL/TLS support. You didn't mention you were moving from home to school, so someone there is your best bet.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for all the help. :)